# Sklearn: Calibrate a multi-label classification with CalibratedClassifierCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I have built a number of sklearn classifier models to perform multi-label classification and I would like to calibrate their `predict_proba` outputs so that I can obtain confidence scores. I would also like to use metrics such as `sklearn.metrics.recall_score` to evaluate them.

I have 4 labels to predict and the true labels are multi-hot encoded (e.g. `[0, 1, 1, 1]`). As a result, `CalibratedClassifierCV` does not directly accept my data:

```py
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=15)
clf = clf.fit(train_X, train_Y)
calibrated_clf = CalibratedClassifierCV(clf, cv="prefit", method="sigmoid")
calibrated_clf.fit(dev_X, dev_Y)
```

This would return an error:

```
ValueError: classes [[0 1]
 [0 1]
 [0 1]
 [0 1]] mismatch with the labels [0 1 2 3] found in the data
```

Thus, I tried to wrap it in a `OneVsRestClassifier`:

```py
clf = OneVsRestClassifier(tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=15), n_jobs=4)
clf = clf.fit(train_X, train_Y)
calibrated_clf = CalibratedClassifierCV(clf, cv="prefit", method="sigmoid")
calibrated_clf.fit(dev_X, dev_Y)
```

Note that `MultiOutputClassifier` and `ClassifierChain` do not work even though they possibly suit my problem better.

It works, but the `predict` output of the calibrated classifier is multi-*class* instead of multi-label because of [its implementation](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0d378913be6d7e485b792ea36e9268be31ed52d0/sklearn/calibration.py#L443). There are four classes (`[0 1 2 3]`) but if there is no need to put a label, it still predicts a `0`.

Upon further inspection by means of calibration curves, it turns out the base estimator wrapped inside the calibrated classifier is not calibrated at all. That is, `(calibrated_clf.calibrated_classifiers_)[0].base_estimator` returns the same `clf` as before calibration.

I would like to observe the performance of my (calibrated) models doing deterministic (`predict`) and probabilistic (`predict_proba`) predictions. How should I design my model/wrap things in other containers to get both calibrated probabilities for each label and comprehensible label predictions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, you're using a `DecisionTreeClassifier` which by default [support targets](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.fit) of dimension (n, m) where m > 1.

However if you want to have as result the [marginal probability](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0d378913b/sklearn/multiclass.py#L471) of each class then use the `OneVsRestClassifier.`

Notice that `CalibratedClassifierCV` expects [target to be 1d](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.calibration.CalibratedClassifierCV.html#sklearn.calibration.CalibratedClassifierCV.fit) so the "trick" is to extend it to support Multilabel Classification with [MultiOutputClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html#multioutputclassifier).

**Full Example**

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_multilabel_classification
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, StratifiedKFold

import numpy as np

# Generate a sample multilabel target
X, y = make_multilabel_classification(n_classes=4, random_state=0)

y
>>> 
array([[1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0],
       ...
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1]])

# Split in train/test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.9, random_state=42
)

# Splits Stratify target variable
cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=2)

# Decision tree support by default multiclass target or use OneVsRest if marginal probabilities
clf = OneVsRestClassifier(DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=10))

# Calibrate estimator probabilities
calibrated_clf = CalibratedClassifierCV(base_estimator=clf, cv=cv)

# calibrated_clf target is one dimensional, extend classifier to multi-target classification.
multioutput_clf = MultiOutputClassifier(calibrated_clf).fit(X_train, y_train)

# Check predict 
multioutput_clf.predict(X_test[-5:])
>>> 
array([[0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1]])

# Check predict_proba
multioutput_clf.predict_proba(X_test[-5:])
>>>
[array([[0.78333315, 0.21666685],
        [0.78333315, 0.21666685],
        [0.78333315, 0.21666685],
        [0.78333315, 0.21666685],
        [0.78333315, 0.21666685]]),
 array([[0.59166537, 0.40833463],
        [0.59166537, 0.40833463],
        [0.40833361, 0.59166639],
        [0.59166537, 0.40833463],
        [0.59166537, 0.40833463]]),
 array([[0.61666922, 0.38333078],
        [0.61666427, 0.38333573],
        [0.80000098, 0.19999902],
        [0.61666427, 0.38333573],
        [0.61666427, 0.38333573]]),
 array([[0.26874774, 0.73125226],
        [0.26874774, 0.73125226],
        [0.45208444, 0.54791556],
        [0.26874774, 0.73125226],
        [0.26874774, 0.73125226]])]
```

Notice that the result from `predict_proba` is a list with 4 arrays, each array is the probability to belong to the class i. For example, inside the first sample of the first array is the probability that first sample belongs to class 1 and so on.

Regarding the calibration curves, scikit-learn provides examples to plot probability path for [two dimension](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/calibration/plot_calibration_curve.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-calibration-plot-calibration-curve-py) and [three dimension](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/calibration/plot_calibration_multiclass.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-calibration-plot-calibration-multiclass-py) targets.

Comment: Thank you, the calibrated model now gives outputs in desired formats. The curve of the calibrated model turns out to be more erratic than not calibrated, and its performance worsens after calibration. Is this an expected behaviour?

Comment: @ivsiquadrus are you using a decision tree based model? in that case the curves will be kind of "erratic" due to the nature of the algorithm, predictions tend to be around the center rather than the extremes

Comment: also how are you evaluating the calibration? [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/calibration/plot_calibration.html) is a good example using the brier score

Comment: I see; I tried to repeat the process of plotting calibration curves and evaluating F1 scores on other models such as XGBoost's gradient boosted classifier, and it seems that the calibration improve the probabilities rather little and it does impact the F1 scores negatively (e.g. decreased by 0.05-0.10). I have computed the Brier scores for all four labels using the XGB model, and the calibrated models have a higher Brier score (higher by 0.001) in all but one labels, where calibration seemed effective.